# Find location of last clicked hyperlink programmatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, visual-basic

I am in need to find the location (i.e. cell and spreadsheet within the same xlsx file) of the last clicked hyperlink, being in another spreadsheet called by the hyperlink itself.
The reason is that from this "called" spreadsheet I would like to read cells on the side of the hyperlink in the "caller" spreadsheet and show them in different formatting and so on.
And the same spreadsheet can be called by different hyperlinks, each of them having different values on the side. Is there any way to do that?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your hyperlink the **Inserted** type or the **=HYPERLINK() function** type ??

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

1. Create a VBA macro that takes the hyperlink as parameter
2. In the macro:
   a. Store the hyperlink so that it is accessible where you need it
   b. Link to / Open the new document.